# Javascript filter vs map problem

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

As a continuation of my min/max across an array of objects I was wondering about the performance comparisons of filter vs map.

So I put together a test on the values in my code as was going to look at the results in FireBug.

This is the code:

```
var _vec = this.vec;
min_x = Math.min.apply(Math, _vec.filter(function(el){ return el["x"]; }));
min_y = Math.min.apply(Math, _vec.map(function(el){ return el["x"]; }));
```

The `map`ped version returns the correct result. However the `filter`ed version returns NaN. Breaking it out, stepping through and finally inspecting the results, it would appear that the inner function returns the `x` property of `_vec` but the actual array returned from `filter` is the unfiltered `_vec`.

I believe my usage of `filter` is correct - can anyone else see my problem?

Here's a simple test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>S:GTC Map Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function vector(x,y,z) { this.x = x; this.y =y; this.z=z; }
var vec = [];
vec.push(new vector(1,1,1));
vec.push(new vector(2,2,2));
vec.push(new vector(2,3,3));
var _vec = vec;
min_x = Math.min.apply(Math, _vec.filter(function(el){ return el["x"]; }));
min_y = Math.min.apply(Math, _vec.map(function(el){ return el["x"]; }));

document.write("<br>filter = " + min_x);
document.write("<br>map = " + min_y);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

No, the `filter` method doesn't return the unfiletered array. It returns an array containing the items where the inner function returns true.

As you are not returning a boolean value from the inner function, the value is converted to boolean, so the object reference is converted to true. Thus, it returns a new array that contains all the items from the original array.

The `filter` method doesn't do the same as the `map` method. The `map` method is used to convert each item of an array, while the `filter` method is used to select certain items of an array. Comparing the performance between the methods is moot, as only one of them does what you want to do.

Comment: Ahh. It appears I misunderstood how the filter functon works. I was under the impression that it returned a modified object to an array.

Comment: Nope, both map and filter returns new array.

Answer (score 42):

Quoted from:

JavaScript: The Definitive Guide
by David Flanagan

> **map()**
>
> The `map()` method passes each element of the array on which it is
>   invoked to the function you specify, and returns an array containing
>   the values returned by that function.
>
> **For example:**
>
> ```
> a = [1, 2, 3];
>
> b = a.map(function(x) { return x*x; });  // b is [1, 4, 9]
> ```
>
> The function you pass to map() is invoked in the same way as a
>   function passed to forEach(). For the map() method, however, the
>   function you pass should return a value.Note that map() returns a new
>   array: it does not modify the array it is invoked on. If that array is
>   sparse, the returned array will be sparse in the same way: it will
>   have the same length and the same missing elements.
>
> **filter()**
>
> The method returns an array containing a subset of the elements of the
>   array on which it is invoked. The function you pass to it should be
>   predicate: a function that returns true or false. The predicate is
>   invoked just as for forEach() and map(). If the return value is true ,
>   or a value that converts to true, then the element passed to the
>   predicate is a member of the subset and is added to the array that
>   will become the return value.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> ```
> a = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
>
> smallvalues = a.filter(function(x) { return x < 3 });   // [2, 1]
>
> everyother = a.filter(function(x,i) { return i%2==0 }); // [5, 3, 1]
> ```

Comment: The var everyother mislead me at first, it passes a to x, while i is the index of array that we can add and use when we need in map, therefore the method filter of everyother  not handle values in the array a, it handle the index which is i

Answer (score 6):

```
// MAP creates a new array
// MPA return new Array
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var newArr = arr.map((el) => {
  return el * 2;
});

console.log(newArr); //2,4,3,8,10,12,14

// filter() return new Array
var newFilter = arr.filter((el) => {
   return el * 2;
});
console.log(newFilter); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

now you can see I have `return el*2` both for **map** and **filter** they are giving a different output

**Filter()**
The filter() method creates a new array filled with all array elements that pass a test implemented by the function.

If this conditional returns true, the element gets pushed to the output array. If the condition returns false, the element does not get pushed to the output array.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var newFilter = arr.filter((el) => {
  return el > 3;
});
console.log(newFilter);  //[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Map()**
The map() method is used for creating a new array from an existing one, applying a function to each one of the elements of the first array
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

```
var newArr = arr.map((el) => {
  return el * 2;
});

console.log(newArr); //2,4,3,8,10,12,14
```